# Não carrega o style.css no wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Estou estudando Wordpress, mas, não consegui utilizar o functions.php para carregar o stylesheet

Estes são os arquivos

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Tema Estudo
Author: A
Version: 1.0.0
*/

body{
    color:  #4d5a6c !important;
}
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Este é o header</h2>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header();

while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content();

}

get_footer();
?>
```

footer.php

```
<h4>Este é o footer</h4>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php 
function arquivos_estilo(){
    wp_enqueue_style('estilo_principal', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'arquivos_estilo');
```

O porquê não lê o estilo?

O que retorna é o seguinte:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/11\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/localhost\/estudo\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.0.2"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a,b){var c=String.fromCharCode;l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,a),0,0);var d=k.toDataURL();l.clearRect(0,0,k.width,k.height),l.fillText(c.apply(this,b),0,0);var e=k.toDataURL();return d===e}function e(a){var b;if(!l||!l.fillText)return!1;switch(l.textBaseline="top",l.font="600 32px Arial",a){case"flag":return!(b=d([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819]))&&(b=d([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]),!b);case"emoji":return b=d([55358,56760,9792,65039],[55358,56760,8203,9792,65039]),!b}return!1}function f(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.defer=c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var g,h,i,j,k=b.createElement("canvas"),l=k.getContext&&k.getContext("2d");for(j=Array("flag","emoji"),c.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},i=0;i<j.length;i++)c.supports[j[i]]=e(j[i]),c.supports.everything=c.supports.everything&&c.supports[j[i]],"flag"!==j[i]&&(c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&c.supports[j[i]]);c.supports.everythingExceptFlag=c.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!c.supports.flag,c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.everything||(h=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",h,!1),a.addEventListener("load",h,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",h),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),g=c.source||{},g.concatemoji?f(g.concatemoji):g.wpemoji&&g.twemoji&&(f(g.twemoji),f(g.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://localhost/estudo/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.0.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='http://localhost/estudo/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://localhost/estudo/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://localhost/estudo/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.0.2" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Este é o header</h2><h2><a href="http://localhost/estudo/2018/12/31/terceiro-post/">Terceiro post</a></h2>

<p>este é o terceiro</p>
<h2><a href="http://localhost/estudo/2018/12/31/segundo-post/">Segundo post</a></h2>

<p>loremasfas ffsdfsdfsdfsd ssfsdfsdsds</p>
<h2><a href="http://localhost/estudo/2018/12/31/ola-mundo/">Olá, mundo!</a></h2>

<p>Boas-vindas ao WordPress. Esse é o seu primeiro post. Edite-o ou exclua-o, e então comece a escrever!</p>
<h4>Este é o footer</h4>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/estudo/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=5.0.2'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não linkou o css no head, tente assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
```

[get_stylesheet_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_uri/) retorna a url do css do tema habilitado atualmente

Comment: Funcionou do seu jeito, mas, sabe me explicar o porquê o functions não puxou o stylesheet?